# Can you explain it,a lesson in codecademy

Tags: python

I was learning code on codecademy.When I was coding in it.I didn't get a solution of the exercise and I clicked ***Give me the solution*** option
and I got the solution byt I didn't understand the program.The program is this

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3}

stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}

for food in prices:
  print food
  print "price: %s" % prices[food]
  print "stock: %s" % stock[food]
```

Then it prints out

```
orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32
pear
price: 3
stock: 15
banana
price: 4
stock: 6
apple
price: 2
stock: 0
```

Can you explain the process of it.
How it prints the output given above

Comment: But what exactly is unclear for you in this program?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know the question. But I can try to explain the program on a high level without knowing the question.

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3}

stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
```

This is the definition of two dictionaries the first one just stores the price for every fruit the second one stores how many fruits are in the storage (stock).

```
for food in prices: ### For loop iterates over the Keys of the dict (fruitnames)
    print food ## printing current key for iteration
    print "price: %s" % prices[food] ## printing price of the fruit
    print "stock: %s" % stock[food] ## printing stock of the fruit.
```

By the way this looks like Python2 Syntax, because there are no parentheses at the `print` statement. I would highly recommend to learn python3 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have two dictionaries named `prices` and `stock`

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3}
stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
```

You're iterating over the `keys` of `prices` dict by `for food in prices:` this line.

Read the comments of this code:

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2,"orange": 1.5,"pear": 3} #prices dict

stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15} #stock dict

for food in prices: #iterate over the keys of prices dict
  print food #print the key
  print "price: %s" % prices[food] #print the value of prices dict at food key
  print "stock: %s" % stock[food] #print the value of stock dict at food key
```